# Associating select value with model via id attribute using serializeJSON jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, marionette

EDIT:

I realized I originally posted an incoherent question as the behavior was specific to a jquery plugin called serializeJSON, and not Marionette.

I have a form that's defined in a template file. The input fields are collecting the input data via their id attribute like so:

```
<input name="" id="objectName[objectAttribute]">
```

Eventually the object 'objectName' is being deserialized into a Java object on our back-end with attributes that match those like 'objectAttribute'.

However, when I try to accomplish the same affect with a 'select' element, the data from the option element isn't passed back to the back end.

I was doing something like this:

```
<select id="objectName[objectAttribute]">
    <option etc>New</option>
    <option etc>Copy</option>
</select>
```

Does someone know how to accomplish that affect, or can point me to a relevant question or documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing the question and realizing the jquery plugin that was committing the behavior and not marionette, the answer is this:

```
<select name="objectName[objectAttribute]">
```

Rather than being set with the id field.